# Is it possible to include a DOCTYPE declaration in an XML file and have the parser remove it while working?

Tags: xml, entity, doctype, xml-parsing

Or perhaps have the parser just ignore the DOCTYPE tag in some fashion? I have XML files being used as "!ENTITY"s that also themselves need to have "!ENTITY"s and I have included the nested ones in the top-level file, but Visual Studio calls out my references to those in the 2nd-level files as not defined. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question properly, you have one XML file that includes additional, standalone XML data within in.

Are you wrapping the inner XML data in CDATA sections?